# Drush installation in windows

Tags: drush

I'm unable to install drush in windows. I have searched a lot for it but unable to understand. I'm new to drupal.

Answer (score 2):

it's pretty simple in fact all you have to do is download and install Acquia Dev Desktop from this link [dev desktop](https://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop)
and you will have a local dev environnement for drupal with drush included

Answer (score 1):

Here are some guide on how to install Drush on Windows.

From docs.drush.org

> Drush on Windows is not recommended, since Drush's test suite is not
>   running there ([help wanted](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1612)).
>
> [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/downloads) is excellent, and includes Drush. See the terminal
>   icon after setting up a web site.
>
> Or consider running Linux/OSX via
>   Virtualbox. [Drupal VM](http://www.drupalvm.com/) and [Vlad](https://github.com/hashbangcode/vlad) are popular.
>
> These Windows packages
>   include Drush and its dependencies (including MSys).
>      [7.0.0](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/7.0.0/windows-7.0.0.zip) (stable).
>      [6.6.0](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/6.6.0/windows-6.6.0.zip).
>      [6.0](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/6.0.0/Drush-6.0-2013-08-28-Installer-v1.0.21.msi).
>
> Or install LAMP on your own, and run Drush via [Git's shell](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), in order to
>   insure that [all depedencies](https://github.com/acquia/DevDesktopCommon/tree/master/bintools-win/msys/bin) are available.
>
> When creating site aliases for Windows remote machines, pay particular attention to
>   information presented in the `example.aliases.drushrc.php` file,
>   especially when setting values for `'remote-host'` and `'os'`, as these
>   are very important when running `drush rsync` and `drush sql-sync`
>   commands.

http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install-alternative/

https://www.drupal.org/node/594744

https://modulesunraveled.com/drush/installing-drush-windows